# How to take data from 2 databases (with same schema) and copy it into 1 database using Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to take data from 2 databases and copy(coalesce) it into 1 using Data factory.

The issue is: **It seems that multiple inputs is not allowed for copy activities.**

So i resorted to having 2 different datasets which are exact copies but with a different name... and then putting 2 different activities into the 1 pipeline which use their specific output dataset.

It just seems odd and wrong to do it this way.

Can i have some help.

This is what my diagram currently looks like:
[image]

Is there no way of just copying data from 2 seperate databases (which have the same structure but different data) to the 1 database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. But you need to work within the constraints of how ADF handles this.

A couple of things to help...

- You'll always need at least 2 activities to do this when using the copy type activity. Microsoft of course charges per activity execution in ADF, so they aren't going to allow you to take shortcuts having many inputs and output per single copy activity (single charge).
- The approach you show above is ok and to pass the ADF validation as you've found you simply need to have the output datasets created separately and called different things. Even if they still refer to the same underlying target table etc. This is really **only a problem for the** **copy activity**. What you could do is land the data firstly into separate staging tables in the Azure target database just for the copy (1:1). Then have a third downstream activity that executes a stored procedure that does the union of tables. In this case you could have 2 inputs to 1 output in the activity if you want to have that level of control in ADF.

Like this:

[image]

- Final point, if you don't want the activities to execute in parallel you could chain the datasets to enforce a fake dependency or add a simple 'delay' clause to one of the copy operations. A delay on an activity would be simpler than provisioning a time slice offset.

Hope this helps